# Get the last tracks played by the user using Spotify API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, spotify

I am trying to get last tracks played by user from Spotify API, and I also check from the documentation from Spotify. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any useful information. So, Could anyone can help me to get the last tracks, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web API doesn't **currently** contain an endpoint to retrieve a user's play history. Please keep an eye out for updates on the [Spotify Web API change log](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/change-log/).

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for your kindly response. I'll keep an eye on it!

Answer (score 2):

You could ask your user to scrobble the songs to last.fm from the Spotify client. Then you can retrieve someones play history from the last.fm API.
http://www.last.fm/api

[image: Enable scrobbling in Spotify]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's Spotify integration offers the following API method:

https://graph.facebook.com/me/music.listens

You must give permission to **user_actions.music** on get user access token